# Disable ICMP reply on CentOS 7 firewall, except some IP blocks

Tags: centos7, ping, firewalld, icmp, firewall-cmd

I have a Centos 7 machine with FirewallD, and net.ipv4.conf.icmp_echo_ignore_all is set to 0.
I'm seeking for some firewall configs to disable ping replies to external IP addresses, but allow some IP blocks (like 192.168.1.0/24, 10.0.0.0/8 etc.) to get ping replies.

How can I do that?

Comment: I can give you the solution, but the firewall configuration is a complex task, not simple. Better read the iptables tutorial to understand basics of the linux firewall.

Comment: Thanks. I'm familiar with Iptables, but could not find a way to implement the solution using FirewallD.

Comment: https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/introduction-to-firewalld-on-centos/ - quick start guide for the firewalld.

Comment: I checked the link and could not find anything about ICMP

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `iptables`

```
[root@ttucker ~]# iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
[root@ttucker ~]# iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255 -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
[root@ttucker ~]# iptables -A INPUT -p ICMP --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
```

Here is what it should look like after wards:

```
[root@ttucker ~]# iptables -v -n -L INPUT | grep icmp
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            source IP range 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255 icmptype 8
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            source IP range 10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255 icmptype 8
    0     0 DROP       icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
```

Iptables works by evaluating the rules it has in order from top to bottom on a given chain. In this instance it is the INPUT chain. When iptables finds a rule which matches it's conditions, it takes the action specified in `-j`.

So, in this example, we are stating that if the source is from 10.0.0.0/8 or 192.168.0.0/16, the action is `ACCEPT`. If the source address is not in that range then it hits the third rule which states to `DROP`.

*Note: you also need to make sure that you currently don't have any current rules which accept all ICMP traffic that are prior to these rules.*

The `-A INPUT` means to append to the `INPUT` chain. So, you first want to list the entire input chain and delete any other ICMP rules which exist there.

Here is how to list the INPUT chain rules:

```
iptables -v -n -L INPUT
```

Please let me know if this works for you or if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm looking for a FirewallD solution. I have no plan to use Iptables on this machine.